# Objective-C How to list all available encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding

In Java I can get all the available encodings with this code:

```
SortedMap<String, Charset> availableCharsets = Charset.availableCharsets();
Vector allEncodes = new Vector();
for (Map.Entry<String, Charset> entry : availableCharsets.entrySet()) {
            allEncodes.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Then, I can read any file with any encode I want:

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(aPath), allEncodes.get(0) );
```

So, is there any idea how to implement this in Objective-C

Comment: If I dare make a not-strictly unrelated comment (since JWWalker has already supplied what I think is the correct answer); in Cocoa the conversion to a string is an atomic act that starts with a blob of data — there's no analogue of setting an encoding on an incoming stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less translation of your code from Java. You need also to complete the code checking `readingError` variable. Of course, central point is `avaiableStringEncodings` static message.

```
  NSMutableArray *arrayOfEncodings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  const NSStringEncoding *encodings = [NSString availableStringEncodings];
  while (*encodings != 0){
    [arrayOfEncodings addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:*encodings]];
    encodings++;
  }

  NSError *readingError = nil;
  NSString yourPath = @"some path you want";
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:yourPath    options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&readingError];

  NSStringEncoding firstEncoding = (NSStringEncoding) [((NSNumber *) [arrayOfEncodings objectAtIndex:0]) intValue];

  NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:firstEncoding];
```

Comment: 1 > "while loop" will never end 2 > [link](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/3034/screenshot20121218at109.png)

Comment: sorry, i edited code withoud Xcode. I tested with IDE now and it's ok.

Comment: check again answer since i roughly translated java code. In array also negative values are present. I think that are coming from CFStringEncodingExt.h. Filter positive values if you want only ones from NSStringEncoding

Comment: enjoy the beauty of stackoverflow and do not forget to read FAQ for a better answer/question management

Answer (score 3):

`const NSStringEncoding* encodingArray = [NSString availableStringEncodings];`